# setuptools is not available in the build environment error when installing pyinotify using pip

Tags: python, windows, cmd, pip

```
C:\Users\misba>pip install pyinotify
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Collecting pyinotify
  Using cached pyinotify-0.9.6.tar.gz (60 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [2 lines of output]
      Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
      ERROR: Can not execute `setup.py` since setuptools is not available in the build environment.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

so when I installed some pip package I got an error, I ran it with pip3 it was the same, how can I solve this problem

this is my pip version

```
pip 23.3.1 from C:\Users\misba\Lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.12)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/pyinotify/#history), this package has not been updated since Jun 4, 2015. But you're using `Python 3.12` which is the newest major release of the Python programming language. This would obviously lead to compatibility issues.

My suggestion is that you try using an older version of python. Creating virtual environments whilst specifying an earlier python version (perhaps python 3.3 or 3.4) would come in handy here.

Answer (score 0):

`pyinotify` is only for Linux. You're trying to install it to the wrong operating system.

If you want a portable filesystem event monitoring look at https://pypi.org/project/watchdog/ . In addition it is more fresh.